# Google map v2 android method getMap() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

In my application I am using google map programmatically, but when I call getMap() it returns null.
even I have tried onActivityCreated() but still it returns null.
somebody please help me..
Here is my code,

```
public void callMap() {
        try {
            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mActivity);
            if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                Log.d("sreedhu", "Google Play Service Available");
                gmo = (new GoogleMapOptions()).zoomControlsEnabled(true)
                        .rotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(gmo);
                map=mapFragment.getMap();   
                manager=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager
                .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapFragmentHole, mapFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();           
                manager.executePendingTransactions();
                            mapFragment=getMap();
            } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
                ErrorDialogFragment.newInstance(status).show(
                        getFragmentManager(), "errorDialog");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Google Map v2 not available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mActivity.popFragments();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("sreedhu", "play" + e.toString());
        }



    }
```

Comment: post ur logcat output..!

Comment: since I wrote everything under try catch it shows only null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

executePendingTransactions seems not work like you expect it.

When MapFragment is created from code, you won't get GoogleMap from it until its onCreateView is called.

You need to call `map=mapFragment.getMap();` and all code after it in onStart or onResume.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the fix for this problem...

I include this below piece of snippet on onCreateView which solved my problem,

```
SupportMapFragment mFragment;
     mFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                    if ((map = mFragment.getMap()) != null) {
                        setUpMap();
                    }
                }
            };
```

Once the map is prepared the SuppotMapFragment's onActivityCreated will get called there you can setup your map.