# How to get GoogleMap Reference - Android google map API

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I struggled to use the google map Android API

The situation is that: I have a parent fragment which holds a reference to a MapFragment.
My goal is just adding  some markers to the map.

The MapFragment always return null in the onViewCreated method, which is expected because the mapFragment layout may not have been completely loaded at that moment.

```
void onViewCreated(){

   GoogleMap sMap = mapFragment.getMap(); //<---- always return null
   // add markers
   //.....
}
```

I tried to put the MapFragment.getMap() in the an AysnkTask and use a while loop to try to hold a reference to the map, but it does not work. A strange exception occurred.

```
void onViewCreated(){
           AsyncTask<Object, Object, GoogleMap> loadInstruction = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, GoogleMap>(){

            @Override
            protected GoogleMap doInBackground(Object... params) {

                GoogleMap sMap = mapFragment.getMap();
                while(sMap == null) {
                    sMap = mapFragment.getMap();
                }
                return sMap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(GoogleMap result) {
                //add Markers 
                                    //......
            }

        };

           loadInstruction.execute();
```

Exception

```
06-23 11:28:05.754: I/dalvikvm(4129): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
06-23 11:28:05.754: I/dalvikvm(4129): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129): Process: com.wenchao.map, PID: 4129
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at kbh.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at lxn.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at lxm.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at fnb.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at   android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
 06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-23 11:28:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 11:28:06.914: I/Process(4129): Sending signal. PID: 4129 SIG: 9
```

Since the getMap() is not guaranteed to return a map reference at anytime, and there is no hook method or somewhere for me to register a callback. And a background async task does not seems to be allowed, how do you determine when to call getMap() and get a map reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this below piece of snippet on onCreateView which will solv your problem,

```
   SupportMapFragment mFragment;
        mFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                if ((map = mFragment.getMap()) != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }
        };
```

Once the map is prepared the SuppotMapFragment's onActivityCreated will get called there you can setup your map.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Google map v2 android method getMap() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967000/google-map-v2-android-method-getmap-returns-null)

Solution in above link works for me. 
Although I have not find docs saying the getMap() will garautuee to return a useful map reference in onActivityCreated, calling the getMap there seems to work.